# Angular (8) - Unit testing service with private variables

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am wondering if my approach to the service I am building and testing is the right approach or not. I have always designed my classes to be as encapsulated as possible. So when it came to building my angular services, I built them the same way.

Below is a snippet of how my service looks:

```js
private postUrl = 'https://localhost:44359/api/posts';
private currentGetPostsUrl = `${this.postUrl}?page=${this.pageNumber}&pageSize=${this.pageSize}`;

private filteredPostListSource = new Subject<IPostViewDto[]>();
filteredPostList$ = this.filteredPostListSource.asObservable();

// post list returned from the api
private originalPostList: IPostViewDto[];
// filtered list that is displayed to user
private filteredPostList: IPostViewDto[];

//get a list of posts that are paginated
getPosts(): Observable < IPostViewDto[] > {
  const urlToFetch = `${this.postUrl}?page=${this.pageNumber}&pageSize=${this.pageSize}`;

  // if the post list exists, return that post list
  if(this.originalPostList) {
  return of(this.originalPostList);
}

return this.http.get<IPostViewDto[]>(urlToFetch, { observe: 'response' })
  .pipe(
    map((response: HttpResponse<IPostViewDto[]>) => {
      const paginationHeader = JSON.parse(response.headers.get('X-Pagination'));
      this.totalCount = paginationHeader.totalCount;
      this.originalPostList = response.body;
      this.filteredPostList = [...this.originalPostList];
      return response.body;
    }),
    catchError(err => this.errorHandler(err))
  );
}
```

Per above, I don't allow components to directly access the private variables and instead have methods through which all interaction is done. The issue here is that unit testing is a bit of a mess. If I want to correctly test that my `getPosts()` method correctly returns the list of posts in my `originalPostList` if it exists, I'd have to run it once after creating a stub value for the http get to ensure the private field gets set, then run it again and compare my stub value equals the 2nd run of `getPosts()`.

This seems like its not only a bad unit test, but maybe the service itself is not built correctly to be tested.

What would be the best way to restructure this to be easily testable? Do I just create getters/setters and test against those? Or is my approach I described above valid?

---

Do note that the reason why I designed it this way is because I didn't want child components / other components to accidentally update these properties without an explicit method call (so that I can write tests to ensure that is the case). Its not because a single component is the only one accessing this service.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I agree that you should not access the private variables in your tests. If you do, your test will be useless when you need to do some refactoring.

I don't see an issue with calling the method twice in your tests. I am assuming it will happen in actual code since you are implementing a caching mechanism. "The more your tests resemble the way your software is used, the more confidence they can give you."

Answer (score 0):

You can create either getter method for accessing private variable or you can change it to public and add `readonly` to it. That way other components/tests can access it but cannot change it.

In my opinion you should not have to call methods twice to test them. Taken from your example I would probably create a function that accepts GET parameters. Once you have that you can test that you are hitting correct API endpoint and getting correct data object via HttpClientTestingModule.